# Apache camel synchronize file routes

Tags: java, mysql, synchronization, apache-camel

I got some data in three seperate csv files which need to be imported into a MySQL database.
So i got three camel routes each one reading from a file and then inserting/updating the DB.

One of those three files contains the datasets that are inserted and the other two are updating the data from the first one which just got inserted.

```
CSV-File-1 -> INSERT INTO table (id,...) VALUES ($id,...)
CSV-File-2 -> UPDATE table SET field = $value WHERE id = $idFromTheJustInsertedDataset
CSV-File-3 -> UPDATE table SET field = $value WHERE id = $idFromTheJustInsertedDataset
```

(id here is not an auto_increment number generated from MySQL)

The problem now is that when route one to insert the data doesn't run before the other 2 the data is lost because I don't get any error from mysql (id just doesn't exist because it has not been inserted yet - query is still valid).

So the file consumer of camel just starts every xxx milliseconds and I don't know any possibility to determine in which order these three routes should run. It is also not possible to consume another file (once) inside of a route - at least I can't figure out how this could be done.

Anyone knows how I could synchronize these routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good option could be:

1. Route 1 (for CSV-File-1) leave it as it is.
2. For `route 2` and `route 3` add `doneFileName` option and generate `.done` files from a bean at the end of the `route 1`. Thus the processing will start only then `route 1` is finished

Answer (score 0):

A rule of thumb as stated inside [Camel's documentation](http://camel.apache.org/parallel-processing-and-ordering.html) for parallel processing is to treat each message as an atomic unit. So, maybe you could redesign a bit your program to treat first the file contening data to insert then once this first step is done you process the others files.

Comment: Exactly this is my problem: How can I ensure that route one which inserts the data is done before one of the other two routes start? All three routes got to read from a file and the only way to start them afaik is to use "<from uri="file:...."/>" and this way there is no control about that

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to have two batchs. The first one contains a directory with all data to insert and delete or move data once processed. The second batch is automatically launched when there is no more data inside the preceding directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you can have two routes, one for reading from the directory and other route should be called from the end of the first route. first route will insert into DB and second will update record.
form("Route Name")
.routeId("InsertRoute")
.bean(InsertDB.class, "insertIntoDB()")
.to("direct:updateRoute");

form("direct:updateRoute")
.routeId("updateDBRoute")
.bean(UpdateDB.class, "updateData()")
.end();
```

This should make sure that modification will run only after insert is completed.
However in this approach, you will not have any listener for update file. So all update files need to be read manually inside UpdateDB class.

Comment: In this case data can be lost if the DB goes down in after route 1 is executed and before route 2 starts because route 2 is never started independent

Comment: For this you should make sure that all the DB operations are part of one route only and use .transacted() at the start of route. If you must implement two routes then add .onException() in second route and place some file which may contain the delete query for all the inserted data from route1. Now place this delete query file in some folder, for which you will have to write a route in a new route builder class. In new route you can set .maximumRedeliveries(). However i prefer placing all db operation in 1 route only.